# Short story in which social scientist writes constitution of sewing circle to win a bar bet, ends up fearing for his life

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, politics

Two guys have an argument in a bar about the value of social science versus physical science. Maybe they're academics. The first guy offers to prove social science works by writing the constitution of a sewing circle (or some other trivial group) to make it grow. Cut to future, the same guy is in fear of his life. The sewing circle is taking over the country, they want to kill the one man who knows their secret.

Comment: Is this science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: @anaranjada - It falls under the heading of scifi, kinda.

Comment: The word "science" in "social science": that's the science.  The idea that social science has value:  That's fiction.  QED.

Comment: Social science has a lot of value. It's simply that (a) its conclusions are often "fuzzier" than the natural sciences and (b) many people do it very badly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is "[The Snowball Effect](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56272)" by [Katherine Maclean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katherine_MacLean) (1952).

> A sociology professor, challenged to prove his theories of the dynamic
> growth of organizations, rewrites the rules of a smalltown sewing
> circle to have "more growth drive than the Roman Empire." He is far
> more successful than he ever anticipated. Originally in Galaxy Science
> Fiction (September, 1952).

You can read the full story online [here](http://freeclassicshortstories.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/the-snowball-effect-by-katherine-maclean.html)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much. I've been searching for years.

Comment: Just pointing out that the thing you click to mark the answer as accepted does not look like a tick until it's ticked. Right now it looks like a star in a circle. I mention it because this took me a little while to work out the first time.

Comment: @Richard, Can't do a "blushes" emoticon here. OK, I get it now! And it's a great story. Totally is one of my favourites. So there.